# Can emacs beautify existing tcl source code?

Tags: formatting, code-folding, programming, icicles, prettify-symbols-mode

I'm just getting started with tcl; what sort of beautifier, or prettifier, or formatter, is there for tcl with emacs?

My main interest would be to fix existing scripts so that particularly the indenting is consistent and the braces, brackets and parenthesis line up nicely.

It doesn't have to be perfect.  Perhaps it's the nature of tcl that this is more difficult than for Java?

Comment: The `indent-region` command is available from `tcl-mode` menu. You can first do `C-x h` (`mark-whole-buffer`) to be able to indent the whole buffer.

Comment: @JeanPierre make that an answer, it works perfectly